# AioHttp: How can I create a data form for an aiohttp post

Tags: python, asynchronous, session, python-requests, aiohttp

This is what the data looks like when I'm using requests and it works fine.

```
data ={
      "srt": srt,
      "firstname" : firstname,
      "lastname" : lastname,
      "Email" : email,
      "password" : password,
      "promotion" : "true",
      "action" : {"name":"EMAIL_REG_FORM_SUBMIT"},
      "ri" : "NORU",
      "ets" : ets
          }
```

I'm trying to convert it so that it works with aiohttp and this is what I have. I think I'm getting an error because of line: `"action" : {"name":"EMAIL_REG_FORM_SUBMIT"},`

```
data = aiohttp.FormData()
data.add_field("srt", srt)
data.add_field("firstname", firstname)
data.add_field("lastname", lastname)
data.add_field("Email", email)
data.add_field("password", password)
data.add_field("promotion", 'true')
data.add_field("action", {"name":"EMAIL_REG_FORM_SUBMIT"})
data.add_field("ri", 'NORU')
data.add_field("ets", ets)
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to make this work pls leave a comment. Essentially I need an async requests with a session, if you know how to do that pls let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get a submission of a full dictionary in a field by simply converting it to a JSON string:

```py
data.add_field("action", json.dumps({"name":"EMAIL_REG_FORM_SUBMIT"}))
```

Depending on the data in the dictionary, you might need to add a serialization class to `json.dumps` to handle "special" data types that `json.dumps` default serialization class can't handle or for which you need to serialize to JSON following some special format (for example converting a DateTime with time zone to some special text format the server is expecting)

You can also add files with additional calls to add_field, specifying the name of the file you have in the form field(s) as the `name` field of your `data.add_field()` call.

Under the hood, FormData tries to transform all your fields and files in a properly formatted `multipart/form-data` payload.

(I found out most of this after fighting a whole day with both the aiohttp client docs and the server I was submitting data to that was doing "unsmart" things)